# magento 2 Addtocart success message

Tags: magento2

I need to know once addto cart the product the success message shows ,but this is from template file not in controller,how to implement this in magento 2 .how the success reponse and sent when this message shows. When this success message trigger ,i need to extend the time to show this message.

can anyone explain me?

Comment: please explain what you want to do

Comment: when this message trigger ,i need to extend the time to show this message .